# Which of Jupiter’s Galilean moons would be easiest to establish a permanent presence on?

Tags: colonization, moons, natural-resources, planetary-resources

The moons of Jupiter are numerous and varied. Which of them would be easiest to colonise in terms of technological complexity?

Comment: easiest? in terms of money, time, technological hurdles, local resources?

Comment: What kind of base? A permanent colony? A propellant factory for exploring the other moons? A mining/smelting facility exporting raw materials? A research facility investigating something on that particular moon?

Comment: Have you checked the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonization_of_the_Solar_System -> The Jovian System

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff "a mining/smelting facility..." we arrive in the Jupiter system and the first thing we do is waste all the natural resources?

Answer (score 1):

Callisto.

The other large Jovian moons receive too much radiation from Jupiter's radiation belts (Callisto 0.01rem/day compared to Ganymede 8rem/day, Europa 540 rem/day, Io 3600 rem/day). Callisto is also composed of various ices and rocks providing plenty of building materials for base construction as well as replenishment of consumables.